# Ubuntu 20.04 Complete System Hang

Tags: wine, lutris

I'm new to Ubuntu and have been enjoying it a lot. I've installed Wine, Lutris, VeraCrypt, Discord and a handful of other things and my system frequently freezes completely and leaves no information in any of the logs that I've been able to read in /vars/logs so I have literally no clue why this is happening.

I have a i7 8700k, z370 gaming pro carbon, 16 gb of ram and a 1080 ti. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe the last messages give a clue what was running.  any messages on the hardware console?  of course this could be a hardware glitch.

Comment: Hi @stackatk. Unless you have hard drive issues, I would take a look at the swap memory and increase that to 8Gb. I experienced the same some time ago. good Luck. Search for increasing swap file in ubuntu.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `swapon -s`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.